# Passenger no such file to load --bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger, rvm

I'm trying to deploy a rails app under apache (on Ubuntu 11.04) for the first time and I'm running into some issues. Basically, when I hit the site, I get an error:

no such file to load --bundler

I'm running rails 3.0 under apache and using passenger. Currently, the app lives under a subdirectory of a user directory. I've installed rvm and have pointed apache at the directory. I did a bundle install to install all the gems.

However, I think I may have screwed up by putting the site in a user directory. Should I move it somewhere under /var/www? I'm thinking that it is entirely reasonable that apache is not getting the same gemset that I have installed for the user. What do I need to do to get the user that apache is running under to have the same rvm capabilities?

I'm a bit clueless on what information you guys need to help me, so please clue me in.

Comment: What host are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the necessary gems for Rails? Install bundler by executing `gem install bundler`. Then go into your Rails app and type `bundle install`.

Also, after bundler is installed, type `which bundle` to see if it's in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Arrgh. It put it in the .rvm directory under my root.

To fix this, do I just sudo gem install bundler or...?

Comment: Yeah, if you installed it as root, then you need sudo. However, in my opinion, you should not use rvm as root. It's not recommended.

Comment: Now I'm getting:
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
        bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6